# Переход на страницу обработчика после нажатия Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

Есть форма, по выбору из выпадающего списка направляет на обработчики, но отправляет сразу после выбора из списка.
Есть варианты как сделать так, чтоб переходило на страницу обработчика только после нажатия Submit?

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form" id="red">   
    <select id="country" class="dropdown_2">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Country</option>
    <option value="http://...vara.html">var A</option>
    <option value="http://...varb.html">">Var B</option>
    </select>
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $('#country').on('change', function() {
var url = $(this).val();
if (url) { 
  window.location = url; 
}
return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Эта строка `$('#country').on('change', function() {` означает что при изменении в селекте выполняется код. Если вы хотите что бы код выполнялся при нажатии на сабмит ее нужно записать так:  `$('id кнопки').on('click', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант есть метод `.submit()`:

```
$('form#red').submit(function(){
  alert('Форма #red отправлена на сервер.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решила методом:
-убрала скрипт
- прицепила onclick прям к сабмиту.

```
<input type="submit" value="GO"  onclick = "window.location=document.forms[0].country.options[document.forms[0].country.selectedIndex].value"  />
```